# Scale animation on Samsung devices doesn't work

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, samsung-mobile

I have `fade in` and `fade out` animations in my app , everything works well but today i run it  on Samsung S7 and see that part of animation where view should be scaled didn't work. On other phones everything works well (I have tested on Lenovo, LG and Fly ).

I search a lot and found only that the Samsung Devices have disable scale animation. To make it work i need change `Animation scale`  to `1`  . Then the animation should work. 
But it is so ugly solution , because every user of my app should go Developer option and then change animation scale manually.

Is there any programmatic solution and why Samsung has turned off scale?

Comment: only for system apps, or if you have root access (which user's won't have)